# How to evaluate the integral , $\int_0^y\sqrt{\log(1+1/x)}dx$ as $y$ tens to zero.?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I want to evaluate the integral as y tends to zero. That is,
$\int_0^y\sqrt{\log(1+1/x)}dx$ as $y$ tens to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sqrt{\log(1 + 1/x)} \leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: thanks RRL. really helped me to solve it

Comment: @DilrukGallage: You're welcome.